# Authorize attribute with role failes, but usermanager.IsInRole is true, with Identity 2.x

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to use Identiy 2.1.0 to login against a local database. I am able to successfully authenticate, but for some reason roles don't seem to be working correctly.

But one an action I have decorated with this:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I keep getting redirected to the login.I have a 'UserService' class which wraps the Identity Framework a bit, and I create the identity like this:

```
    public ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentityByName(string uname, string password, string authType)
    {
        var user = _userManager.Find(uname, password);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not log in user " + uname);
        }
        var isAdmin = _userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin");
        return _userManager.CreateIdentity(user, authType);
    }
```

**isAdmin** is set to true, so Identity framework is able to determine that I am in the 'Admin' role.

The created identity is using in my controller like this:

```
    private void SignIn(string uname, string password, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = _userService.CreateIdentityByName(uname, password, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

I have read through other solutions, post here, but none seem to work. I tried enabling lazy loading in my code first context (not that I really want to enable that).

In the web.config, forms authentication is off, which I read as a possible solution.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

One interesting thing in the web config, is that under system.web, authentication mode is set to "none". Not sure if that is correct or not, but that is how VS set it up for me.

In my startup I have:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
    }
```

Other info:
My context and user class look like this:

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{


    public MyContext() : base("MyContext", false)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new DecimalPrecisionAttributeConvention());
    }    


    public DbSet<Material> Materials { get; set; }
}

public class User :  IdentityUser
{

    [NotMapped]
    public string UserId
    { 
        get
        {
            return Id;
        }
        set
        {
            Id = value;
        }
    }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I find it odd that IsInRole() works correctly, but the filter attribute does not seem to be aware of my roles. I was hoping that maybe turning on lazy loading would work because Identity wasn't smart enough to eager load the roles, but it doesn't seem to have mad any difference.

Any pointers here?